# Comparing two Timer values in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, timer, comparison

I have simple game in Swift that uses a Timer object to track how long the user has survived. I want to be able to track their best time. I am currently configuring the timer like this:

```
func startGameTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer() {
    seconds += 1
    activeTimer.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
}

func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
    let minutes = Int(time) / 3600
    let seconds = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let milliseconds = Int(time) % 60
    return String(format:"%02i:%02i.%02i", minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
}
```

When the player loses, their time is displayed as as a String in the format: "mm:ss.ms"

I want to compare the stored value in UserDefaults with the current Timer value to determine which is the best time.

I have seen several questions about Date objects, but this is obviously not a time of day and does not use hours.

What is the best way to compare these values without parsing and comparing each part of the time?

Comment: Store and compare numbers. Only convert to a string for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like var start = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate when you start the timer then var stop = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate then you measure the time and compare it with the one you have in userDefaults.

Comment: While I do believe this would work, I already have the timer set up and working. It'd probably be better to just make the parser and compare ints as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to parse and compare timer values. Again, values are stored as Strings in the format "mm:ss.ms"

This function will set the Best Time variable in UserDefaults to the highest timer value.

```
func determineBestTime() {

    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "bestTime") == nil {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "bestTime")
        bestTimeLabel.text = activeTimerLabel.text
        bestTime = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "bestTime") as! String
    } else {

        let bestTimeValues = bestTime.components(separatedBy: ":")
        let currTimeValues = currentTime.components(separatedBy: ":")

        let bestTimeMin = Int(bestTimeValues[0])!
        let currTimeMin = Int(currTimeValues[0])!

        if currTimeMin < bestTimeMin {
            return
        } else if currTimeMin > bestTimeMin {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "bestTime")
            bestTime = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "bestTime") as! String
            bestTimeLabel.text = bestTime
            return
        }

        let bestTimeVals = bestTimeValues[1].components(separatedBy: ".")
        let currTimeVals = currTimeValues[1].components(separatedBy: ".")

        let bestTimeSec = Int(bestTimeVals[0])!
        let currTimeSec = Int(currTimeVals[0])!

        if currTimeSec < bestTimeSec {
            return
        } else if currTimeSec > bestTimeSec {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "bestTime")
            bestTime = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "bestTime") as! String
            bestTimeLabel.text = bestTime
            return
        }

        let bestTimeMilliSec = Int(bestTimeVals[1])!
        let currTimeMilliSec = Int(currTimeVals[1])!

        if currTimeMilliSec < bestTimeMilliSec {
            return
        } else if currTimeMilliSec > bestTimeMilliSec {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "bestTime")
            bestTime = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "bestTime") as! String
            bestTimeLabel.text = bestTime
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the worst possible solution to your problem. Don't store a string in UserDefaults. Store an `Int`. It's easier to store, easier to compare. Don't convert the `Int` to a `String` until you need to display it in whatever format you desire.

Comment: @rmaddy I know it may not be the best solution, but that is the point of this question. lol However, I may just be misunderstanding you, but I don't think storing an Int is possible. If you look at the initial question, my timer method forms a String of "mm:ss.s", I don't know what you mean by store an Int?

Comment: Your timer is incrementing your `seconds` variable. That is an `Int`. Store that value. Do not store the string you create from the number.

Comment: @rmaddy lol wow, I was completely overlooking that... duh. Phrase that as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you for catching that.